# Autofill in EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a new column and then Auto-filling the new added column with series numbers. I am using below code but Auto-filling is not performing at all in my excel.

```
Sub Macro7()

Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Sr. No"
Dim LR As Long, i&
LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & LR)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fill a column with values or formulas from the cell above, use the `FillDown`.

Also, instead of using `Select`, `Selection` and `ActiveCell` you should use referenced objects, and perform your operations directly on them. I.e , instead of `Range("A1").Select` and `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Sr. No"` , you could write `Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Sr. No"` (there is no formula here, so in this case it should be `Range("A1") = "Sr. No"`).

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro7()

Dim LR As Long, i&

Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

' find last column in Column B (with skipping blank cells in the middle)
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Range("A1") = "Sr. No"
Range("A2").Formula = "=ROW()-1"
Range("A2:A" & LR).FillDown

End Sub
```

**Edit 1**:

```
' find last column in Column B (with skipping blank cells in the middle)
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Range("A1:A" & LR).Formula = "=2*ROW(B1)-1"
```

Comment: Now my column A is getting filled with "Sr. No." only, not with serial numbers.

Comment: And as a series, I want to put numerical entries in it starting from 1.

Comment: so you want to fill cell A2 with 1, A3 with 2, etc.. ? until last row with data in Column B (previously Column A) ?  see edited code if that's what you meant

Comment: Hey, it is still coming with "Sr.No." in the column. I tried something different which is I want to fill A1 with 1, A2 with 3, A3 with 5, etc. a whole odd series auto-fill, I am still trying to find a way to make. If you know any possible way let me know

Comment: @DhruvBhatt try the code under **Edit 1** for you latest request